# SQL: Join tables on substrings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table **A** with the string-column **a** and a table **B** with the string-column **b**. a is a substring of b. Now I want to join the the two tables on **a and b**. Is this possible?

I want something like this:

**`Select * from A,B where A.a *"is substring of"* B.b`**

How can I write this in SQL (Transact-SQL)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

```
select *
from A
  inner join B 
    on B.b like '%'+A.a+'%'
```

Comment: Please don't do this if a lot of the values you're looking at are potentially blank. Speaking from experience, odds are you might end up flooding the whole database network with traffic.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @tmp1 table (id int, a varchar(max))
declare @tmp2 table (id int, b varchar(max))


insert into @tmp1 (id, a) values (1,'one')
insert into @tmp2 (id,b) values (1,'onetwo')

select * from @tmp1 one inner join @tmp2 two on charindex(one.a,two.b) > 0
```

You can also use charindex, 0 means its not found, greater than 0 is the start index

[charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

set an inner join on a substring(4 letters) of FIELD1 of table TABLE1 with FIELD1 of table TABLE2

```
select TABLE1.field1,TABLE2.field1 from TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 on substring(TABLE1.field1,2,5)=TABLE2.field1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from A
Join B on B.b = substr(A.a, 1, 5)
```

The number 1 represents the first character of your string but you would pick the begin and the end of the characters you would like to match of course. Could be 5, 9 too for example.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select * from A,B where B.b LIKE '%'+A.a+'%'
```

Comment: Your LIKE syntax is backwards

Answer (score 0):

You have the contains function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

```
select * from A,B where contains(B.b, A.a)
```