# How to search a table column for each row against another column in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is quite difficult to explain but, I have a table (tenant) with a column called occupant. I want to know if the value in the column fully/partially matches the value in another table (offensive) with only one column called bad_words.

i.e.

```
tbl_Tenant.Occupant
------------------

Julia f*t
P*y Girl
Gary A*e

tbl_Offensive.bad_words
---------
s*t
f*t
p*y
a*e
```

I know the following query is incorrect but I'm trying to do something like this but cant think of the correct way to script it.

```
select * from tbl_tenant t
where t.occupant like '%(select o.bad_words from tbl_offensive o)%'
```

Can someone please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread is very similar: [SQL: Join tables on substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788599/sql-join-with-substrings)

Translated for your tables:

```
Select * 
From tbl_Tenant t 
Inner Join tbl_Offensive As o 
   on ( o.bad_words like '%'+t.Occupant+'%' )
```

Comment: Hi @ArdalanShahgholi, Thanks for your reply. I am searching through circa 6 million records. Is there another optimized version of this code as it's taking forever to run. Also Is there a way to just retrieve records if there is a word for word match i.e. 'John Pussy massod'. This should be returned because 'pussy' was matched. Not because 'ass' was found in 'massod'. Your code finds both 'pussy' and 'massod'

Comment: I slight ly changed the above code to: Select * 
From tbl_Tenant t 
Inner Join tbl_Offensive As o 
   on ( o.bad_words like '% '+t.Occupant+' %' ). This worked wonders. thanks to all who helped. I will vote your answers

Answer (score 1):

It most be work :

```
Select * 
From tbl_Tenant As T
    cross join tbl_Offensive As O
Where ( O.bad_words like '% ' + T.Occupant + ' %' )
  Or
  ( O.bad_words like T.Occupant + ' %' )
  Or
  ( O.bad_words like '% ' + T.Occupant )
```