# How to join tables when entries don't exactly match

Tags: database, sqlite, organization

I have two tables I need to join based on zip code.

Table1:

| ZIP | INCOME |
| --- | --- |
| ZCTA5 01845 | 45,000 |
| ZCTA5 11421 | 52,000 |
| ... | ... |
| ZCTA5 99704 | 42,000 |

There are thousands of entries in Table1

Table2:

| ZIP | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 01845 | Y |
| 11421 | N |
| ... | ... |
| 99704 | Y |

Table1 has several more entries in it than Table2 that I don't need, I'm just trying to get incomes for the zip codes listed in Table2. I figure I can just do an inner join for this, but I'm running into the issue that I have that ZCTA5 preceding the zip code in table1. I was curious if there was a way to do this?

Comment: Your question seems similar to [this one about joins on substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788599/sql-join-tables-on-substrings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `substr` function to extract the zip code from table1, and join on that:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON substr(t1.zip, -5) = t2.zip;
```